# GDM - how to enable touchpad tap-to-click

Tags: arch-linux, gdm3

I've enabled *tap-to-click* in Gnome but it doesn't work on GDM.

I tried running `dconf-editor` as root to modify the setting but to no avail.

I also tried running `sudo -u gdm gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click true` but I get the following error

`(process:16560): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=long-number-here --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1`

How do I enable *tap-to-click* on GDM?

Comment: I don't know about GDM but this has worked on every Arch version I've tried it on:
https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?221-Touchpad-Synaptics-Tapping-issue-Solved

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to export `$(dbus-launch)` and set the `gsettings` backend (tested  on `archlinux` with `gdm 3.18.2`):

1. switch to a `VT` (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>), login as *root* and run:

   ```
   su - gdm -s /bin/sh
   ```

   to switch user to `gdm`.
2. then run:

   ```
   export $(dbus-launch)
   ```

   and:

   ```
   GSETTINGS_BACKEND=dconf gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click true
   ```

   run `exit` or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to return to *root* account.
3. restart the display manager:

   ```
   systemctl restart gdm
   ```

Reverting is pretty much the same, just change `true` to `false` @ step 2.

Comment: In Debian Stretch switch user to `Debian-gdm`: `su - Debian-gdm -s /bin/sh`

Comment: so how do you persist these settings?

Comment: Confirmed working on Fedora 30.

Comment: thank you (F35)

Comment: @Sławek what about Pop! Os?